# How to derive the relationship between the derivatives at two infinitesimally close points on any continuous binary function $f(x,y)$?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

“f” is a binary function of “x” and “y”
$$
\begin{aligned}
d f_2 & =\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right|_{(x+d x, y)} d y 
\end{aligned}
$$
Notice that the equation requires the $y$ partial derivative at $(x+d x, y)$. Because the partial derivative is itself just another function of $x$ and $y$, we may write to leading order in $d x$
$$
\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right|_{(x+d x, y)}=\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right|_{(x, y)}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} d x
$$
Who can help me explain how the second formula is derived?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that $g|_{x+dx} = g(x) + {\partial g\over \partial x}\big|_x dx$ by Taylor's Formula up to the order 1.
This is more a definition than a mathematical truth.
Then apply the above formula with $g = {\partial f\over \partial y}$ to get the answer of your question.